# Easily type Unicode characters using AutoHotKey?

Tags: macros, autohotkey, unicode

For example, I want to be able to type `→` (right arrow) using AutoHotKey's text replacement feature, and this is what my script looks like:

```
::|rarr::{ASC 2192}
```

So when I type `|rarr` in my text editor and hit `, . <SPACE> <ENTER>`, etc the text should be replaced with a `→`. But for some reason, I get this: `É`.

Usually that works for ASCII and ANSI characters. Should it be done differently with Unicode? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code works depends on the receiving application.
The [help](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) says for `{ASC nnnnn}`:

> [...]
>
> Unicode characters may be generated by specifying a number between 256
>   and 65535 (without a leading zero). However, this is not supported by
>   all applications. For alternatives, see the section below.

Relevant section from remarks:

> Unicode characters are supported directly as text in Unicode versions
>   of AutoHotkey, or using {U+nnnn} notation in any version.

So if you are using a Unicode AHK build:

```
::|rarr::→
```

If not:

```
::|rarr::{U+2192}
```

(Tested with AHK Unicode 64-bit 1.1.15.01)

Comment: Hi, I don't think AHK has different versions like you suggest; at least, it's changed since the last time you installed/updated AHK. The website (http://www.autohotkey.com/) only lists one version. Can you please take a good look?

Comment: OK, I just found out that that site is old and this (http://ahkscript.org/) is the new one; how lame of me! By the way, only the last one worked for me, i.e. `::|rarr::{U+2192}`

Comment: @its_me You're using Unicode AHK (check description column in task manager of running script) and the first one doesn't work? What encoding uses your script file? Mine uses UTF-8 (with bit order mark).

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this AHK script to send unicode characters to any application by pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and typing `Character's 4-digit Hex Value`:

```ahk
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Unicode Support
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
#U::SendUnicode()
SendUnicode()
{
    Input, hex, l4
    Send {U+%hex%}
}
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Answer (score 5):

Save the file as `UTF-8 with BOM`.

Comment: It worked fine for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## [Autohotkey-script for converting LaTeX-like input to unicode characters](https://gist.github.com/kbauer/e8fee6514d124d5961f51fd7ba571bfd)

"Ctrl+Alt+Shift+U" toggles it on and off (look at the bottom right icon to see it's in suspense mode (icon S) of active mode (icon H).

Test: αβΓ∞

<sup>See more: [Replacing latex with unicode symbols](https://superuser.com/q/90704/301042)</sup>